# Django packages for cloning Failblog

Tags: python, django, blogs, clone

I'm considering making something similar to [Failblog](http://failblog.org) using Django. That is, a blog where every post has a main picture or a main video, people can comment and vote on them, people can upload pictures and (YouTube-hosted) videos so they will become posts, there's a page where users can vote on those new uploaded items before they're being posted to the main stream, and that's about it. (I want it to be less cluttered than Failblog.)

Could you point me at some Django packages that might be useful for such a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Django basic apps](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps)

Comment: my bad .. put a clone url ;-(